# add 1 to currently value onsubmit

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I'm trying to add 1 to a value on a page whenever the submit button is clicked. the `"total"`(table field name) value is already calculated from the database so when the button is click one should added to it. the records are nested so on each row when you click on the submit button it should add 1 to the currently value

the problem is i'm not able to bind the database value (`total`) in the javascript for it to appear on the page.

when its like this no value appears on the page

```
$http.get('http://localhost/marv/feeds.php').success(function(data){
       console.log(data);
       $scope.feeds=data;
}   
    $scope.total=(data.total);
     $scope.lovepic=function() {
    event.preventDefault();

      $scope.total++;
```

but when like this

```
$http.get('http://localhost/marv/feeds.php').success(function(data){
       console.log(data);
       $scope.feeds=data;
}   
    $scope.total=0;
     $scope.lovepic=function() {
    event.preventDefault();

      $scope.love_total++;
```

zero (`0`) appears on the page, but each row has its own unique value that why i want the zero value to be replaces with the field from the database table called `total`

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="feedsctrl" ng-repeat="item in feeds">
<il>{{total}}</il>
</div>
```

Comment: Put it `$scope.total=data.total;` **inside** your `success` `function` and it should work. Also if you have this `total` *value*  in your `data`, you don't need nothing of this.. just call in your view: `<il>{{item.total}}</il>`; By the way, what tag is `<il>`?

Comment: @developer033, i get NaN, can u phrase what you are saying in a code?

Comment: Is this `total` an attribute of your `data` item? I mean.. can you access `data.total`?

Comment: @developer033 no i can't access it in the json. but it appears in the html

Comment: So, how are you trying to do `$scope.total = data.total`?

Comment: @developer033 can we talk in a chat so i can explain further?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118225/discussion-between-neiza-and-developer033).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you must not use the `success` and `error` methods because they have been deprecated, according to this [**deprecation notice**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice):

> ### Deprecation Notice
>
> The `$http` legacy promise methods `success` and `error` have been deprecated. Use the standard `then` method instead. If `$httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions` is set to `false` then these methods will throw `$http/legacy` error.

Now, regarding to your problem:

The main problem is that you were trying to access the `object` `data` outside of the `success` function. However, you already have the *property* `total` in your `data`, so you don't need to store in a separate variable.

Also to increment the total for each item, you should use `ngClick` directive, as below:

```
ng-click="addComment(item)"

$scope.addComment = function(item) {
   item.total = parseInt(item.total) + 1;
}
```

Here's a *snippet* working:

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

  MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.feeds = [  
      {  
        "comment":"very nice",
        "total":"3",
        "user":"max"
      },
      {  
        "comment":"interesting",
        "total":"8",
        "user":"okonah"
      },
      {  
        "comment":"wow",
        "total":"20",
        "user":"soja"
      }
    ];

    $scope.addComment = function(item) {
      item.total = parseInt(item.total) + 1;
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="item in feeds">
    <ul>
      <li>{{item.comment}}</li>
      <li>{{item.total}} Comments</li>
      <li>Commented by{{item.user}}</li>
    </ul>
    <button ng-click="addComment(item)">add up</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```